# MS Access Report Hyperlink to Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hello I created a database and I'm trying to make it so that when I click on a field in a report it jumps to a form with the relevant field.

I have a table "tblPagers" a Form "frmPagers" and a report Customer Report

In the table I have a field PagerID and User Name... In my report I want to click on the User Name and have it bring me to my frmPagers on the current record. I'm having problems with my Where Condition.

I have:

```
If IsNull([User Name]) Then
Beep
End If
If Not IsNull([User Name]) Then
OpenForm
 Form Name frmPagers
 View Form
Where Condition (this is where I have the problem)
Data Mode Edit
Window Mode Dialog
```

For my where condition I've tried `=="[Pager ID]="&[User Name]`
When I click on a Null User Name it does Beep. However, if I click on a user name I get this error. "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Pager ID]=Sam Hall'."

Comment: For clarity the If IsNull([UserName])Then

Answer (score 0):

Is [Pager ID] a text type field? Does it really store user name text? I suspect no to both.

Try:

```
If IsNull(Me.[User Name]) Then
    Beep
Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmPagers", , , "[User Name]='" & Me.[User Name] & "'", acFormEdit, acDialog
End If
```

If must use macro, the WHERE CONDITION would be like:
`[User Name] = Reports![Customer Report]![User Name]`

Advise no spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention. Better would be UserName or User_Name, PagerID or Pager_ID.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Pager ID is my primary key. User Name is in the same table. Thanks for the advice on naming conventions.

Comment: I don't want the message box because this is just a quick access link from the Report that gets sent to an end user to the Form where the data gets entered.

Comment: The Error is displaying the correct info: Syntax error in string in query expression '[PagerID]='John Doe'. That is the correct User Name for that pager ID. However, it's not opening the form. If I clear out the "Where Condition." The form opens but not to the current record. I'll try to add a photo of the screen cap.

Comment: I'm guessing I can't add a photo because my account is too new... I thought I had a lot more activity on this account. Must have had a different account I used when I was a student because I know I've posted screenshots on here before.

Comment: If PagerID is Autonumber primary key then certainly can't compare it to the text user name. Either change PagerID to UserName or compare to PagerID value. See revised answer.

Comment: I'm using the macro builder. I have it set to {"open form" I have the form selected; view is set to form; filter name is blank; where condition, this is where my problem is. If I just set it to ="[User Name] I get the error.t Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'John Doe'.  If I delete the where condition, then the form opens but not to the correct record.

Comment: I don't use macros so did a test. See revised answer.

Comment: Okay, closer. It opens the form without an error but not to the current record I'm selecting. Just to the first record.

Comment: The technique is correct - tested and works for me. Since I don't know your data structure or form and report designs, really can't say why the code fails.